# _.each vs _.map what is the difference?

Tags: coffeescript, underscore.js

I tried to print all the animals in my list. and I tried to use `_.each` and it work fine. but when I use `_.map`, they have the same result.

**code:**

```
animals = [ "dog","cat","pig" ]
```

using `_.map`:

```
_.map animals, (animal)->
    console.log " " + animal

    //result: dog cat pig
```

using `_.each`:

```
_.each animals, (animal)->
    console.log " " + animal

    //result: dog cat pig
```

**Question:**

1. what is the difference between those two?
2. what is the main/super function of these two?

I am new in JavaScript and I tried to read the [Underscore documentation](http://underscorejs.org/) but i did not understand some of the terminologies.

Comment: Have you read documentation on those functions?

Comment: I am new in JavaScript and I tried to read the Underscore documentation but i did not understand some of the terminologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.each` is just a for-loop that executes the given function for each element.

`_.map` collects the return value of the given function for each element and returns a list of all the return values in order.

If you discard the result of `_.map` (as in your example) it does the same as `_.each` but wastes some memory.

Therefore, *functionally* `_.map` is a superset of `_.each`, but implementation-wise it is unwise to use it if you don't actually need the results.

Answer (score 0):

_.each doesn't return a value while 
_.map returns a value

Example:

```
var animals = [ "dog","cat","pig" ]

var newAnimalEach = _.each(animals,(animal)=>{ return animal+'s'})
console.log(newAnimalEach) // returns [ "dog","cat","pig" ]

var newAnimalMap = _.map(animals,(animal)=>{ return animal+'s'})
console.log(newAnimalMap) // returns [ "dogs","cats","pigs" ]
```